# remove duplicates and it's intrinsec value

Tags: r, vector, duplicates

Suppose the next vector:

```
just_a_random_vector <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
```

The idea is that if certain value has duplicates then drop all duplicate values and the value itself. In order to get something that looks like this:

```
# A  D
```

Is there any way to get the above output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `duplicated` in forward and reverse to return two logical vectors, then use OR (`|`) when either one of them is TRUE, negate (`!`) and subset the vector

```
just_a_random_vector[!(duplicated(just_a_random_vector)|
        duplicated(just_a_random_vector, fromLast = TRUE))]
[1] "A" "D"
```

---

Or another option is `table` to create a logical vector based on the frequency count i.e. count equal to 1 is returned

```
just_a_random_vector [just_a_random_vector %in%
          names(which(table(just_a_random_vector) == 1))]
[1] "A" "D"
```